# How to make logo interchangeable, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a custom CMS Rails app for a local company, and had the request to allow the logo to be interchangeable for the holidays. For example, they talked about having choices of different logos for each holiday.

I am imaging a radio button looking something like this

- Normal
- Christmas
- Christmas1
- Easter
- Easter1
- Thanksgiving
- 4th of July
- etc

So, does anyone have any idea how I would implement this, or have any experience with it?

I have an admin panel for them and I am thinking of adding a section that has the radio buttons mentioned above, and depending on what one is set a variable changes values and displays a different logo from the images folder, but not sure if that's the route to go.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** Sounds like I have the right idea, can I get some advice from you experts on how you would go about implementing this? I'm thinking of having a logo model where they can upload the image to, but how would I implement that into the view  to allow them to pick?

Comment: I would say you've got the right idea :)

Comment: I dint actually get what you are doing but i would say look for **CSS Sprites** I hope thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse two different things you will store in the database: the list of logos, and the setting of the current logo. The former will consist of a model and a table. The latter could be a simple foreign key pointing to the correct entry in that table.

You should also have a new controller since you plan to let them manage the list of logos. For image uploading check out [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) which has comprehensive examples.

Comment: I am thinking of having a logo model with the following fields, name:string, image:string (for Carrierwave) default:boolean (to track the current logo) So the setting of the logo would just change the boolean value of whatever logo to true. Sound good?

Comment: A good database design avoids the possibility of putting the data in an inconsistent state. Consider: 1) When you switch to another logo you need to toggle `default` back to false in your previous one. 2) You have to remember to do that as well if you change the logo programmatically from anywhere else in the code, maybe 6 months from now, otherwise you end up with two in-use logos which leads to subtle bugs.