# Making the logo interchangeable. Should I do it through the scss.erb or in the applications layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, carrierwave

I am trying to make the logo of my rails app interchangeable, see previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116702/how-to-make-logo-interchangeable-ruby-on-rails)

I have a Logo model which has the following fields name:string, image:string, default:boolean

I am using the carrierwave gem to upload an image to the image:string column.
app/models/logo.rb

```
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :image, LogoUploader
scope :default, where(default: true)

def falsify_all_others
  Logo.where('id != ?', self.id).each do |item|
    item.default = false
    item.save
    end
  end
end
```

I have a logos controller, seen here
app/controllers/logos_controller.rb

```
class LogosController < ApplicationController
def new
  @logo= Logo.new
end

def create
  @logo = Logo.new(params[:logo])
  if @logo.save
    @logo.falsify_all_others
    redirect_to logos_path, :notice => "Logo has been uploaded successfully"
  else
  render "new"
  end
end

def edit
  @logo = Logo.find(params[:id]) 
end

def destroy
  @logo = Logo.find(params[:id])
  @logo.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Logo has been obliterated!"
  redirect_to logos_path
end

def update
  @logo = Logo.find(params[:id])

  if @logo.update_attributes(params[:logo])
    @logo.falsify_all_others
    flash[:notice] = "Logo has been changed successfully!"
    redirect_to logos_path
  else 
    flash[:alert] = "Logo has not been updated."
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end

def show
  @logo = Logo.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @logos = Logo.all
end 
end
```

and my applications controller

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :get_logo

def get_logo
  @logo_default = Logo.default
end
```

So, once they have created/uploaded a few images through carrierwave, I display the logo like this: 
app/views/logos/show.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @logo.image_url.to_s %>
```

I want to add the default logo (which I find through my logos scope) to display on the home page. Right now, it is done through the app/assets/stylesheets/styles.scss.erb through this code

```
section#header {
height: 220px;
position: relative;
h1 {
    background-image: url('<%= asset_path 'logo.png' %>');
    position: absolute;
    width: 412px;
    height: 188px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

So my question is this: Do I need to pull the code that displays the logo out of the scss.erb and add to to the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, or can I change it in the scss? like replace asset_path with an image_tag, or something like that? Let me know if you need more info/code i'll be happy to provide... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to put it in the scss, because you'll likely want to precompile all this static stuff in production.

Comment: Can you tell me more what you mean by 'because you'll likely want to precompile all this static stuff in production' Should I not be putting any images in the css?

Comment: Static images are no problem at all. But if I got you right, you want to replace this image, so it should not be part of the (if precompiled) static files. In case you want to read about precompiling, see [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production). Beside this, even if you really would dynamically replace the image in the stylesheets, the client won't be able to cache your css, so I think putting it in your views is the right way.